# how to add menuItemClick event when menuItem is created programatically in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-controls

In my asp.net web application, i have created a menu and menuItem programatically based on the Logged in user role.The Code is given below...

```
    Menu menu = new Menu();
    menu.CssClass = "menu";
    menu.IncludeStyleBlock = false;
    menu.EnableViewState = false;
    menu.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

    if (roleType.equals("teacher"))
    {
        MenuItem categoryItemCh1 = new MenuItem("Home");
        categoryItemCh1.NavigateUrl = "Teacher/TestsList.aspx";
        menu.Items.Add(categoryItemCh1);

        MenuItem categoryItemCh2 = new MenuItem("Account");
        categoryItemCh2.NavigateUrl = "Account/underconstruction.aspx";
        menu.Items.Add(categoryItemCh2);

        MenuItem categoryItemCh3 = new MenuItem("Reports");
        categoryItemCh3.NavigateUrl = "Account/underconstruction.aspx";
        menu.Items.Add(categoryItemCh3);

        MenuItem categoryItemCh4 = new MenuItem("Logout");
        menu.Items.Add(categoryItemCh4);
    }
```

So, When user clicks the logout menu item , then i have to fire menuItem click event to do the following process.

1.Clear all the session associated with the user
  2.Redirect to Login page.

But i don't know how to add a menuItem click event programatically in asp.net.Please guide me to get out of this issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [MenuItemClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.menuitemclick.aspx) event.  You don't add an event to each menu item but to the menu itself

```
menu.OnMenuItemClick += Menu_MenuItemClick;


void Menu_MenuItemClick(Object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
// Display the text of the menu item selected by the user.
Message.Text = "You selected " + 
  e.Item.Text + ".";
}
```

You can use the MenuEventArgs to figure out which menu item was clicked

Answer (score 0):

To add event handlers to the menu, you'll need to use either the AddHandler or AddHandlers methods on the menu's EventHandlerList. To get the EventHandlerList, see the Menu.Events property.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the problem...

```
    protected void RadMenu2_ItemClick(object sender, RadMenuEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (RadMenu2.SelectedItem.Text)
        {
            case "Menu Text 1":
                Your code or method;
                break;
            case "Menu Text 2":
                Your code or method;
                break;
            case "etc...":
                Your code or method;
                break;        
        }
```